# how to kill threads using cyclic barrier

Tags: java, concurrency, cyclicbarrier

Is there a way to kill all the threads waiting for cyclic barrier to complete.
In my scenario I have 3 threads which if meet at point A then only proceed otherwise the process should be killed. I have used cyclic barrier to check if all three threads are meeting at point A, if yes then proceed but if even 1 thread fails then how can i kill all the threads using this barrier. Thet threads are just waiting. I dont want them to wait now.

Answer (score 1):

When some thread going to fail in achiving "meeting point A", it can *manually break the barrier*:

```
// Fail code
Thread.currentThread.interrupt(); // Set *interrupt* status for current thread
try {
    barrier.await(); // Because of interrupt status, this will immediately throw exception and mark barrier as broken.
} catch(InterruptedException e) {}
// Other finalization code if needed.
```

So any other thread will get `BrokenBarrierException` exception whenever it attempts to use `.await` on this barrier.